# Reduce query time for lcoaiton search in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have a table in Postgresql with four columns as ID,x,y,z. I want to reduce my query time for the following query:

```
SELECT ID
from table
WHERE X between X1 AND X2 AND
      Y between Y1 AND Y2 AND
      Z between Z1 AND Z2;
```

Currently, I am having query time fo 10-15 seconds due to a large database and I want to reduce the time. Given that for each x,y,z there will be only one row that will match the output, how can I create multiple indices so that the query results can be fetched much faster?

Apologies for an open-ended question but I am stuck here and not sure what to do next.

Query Expalin Analyze Result:

[image]

Comment: That's an invalid SQL query to begin with. If you want tuning help, then please **[edit]** your question and add the complete query you are using and its [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Won't creating a usual (b-tree) index for `X` help?

Comment: "Given that for each x,y,z there will be only one row that will match the output". You mean all three of them are individually unique?  That doesn't get you very far considering you are using range queries.

Comment: Is this reproducible?  Notice that the time reported by your top node is 1000 fold less than the total time, which is hard to explain.  What version are you using?